# How do I set HH:mm format with sliders into textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

quickly said, is there a possibility to bind two sliders into one TextBox?

Bassically:

I would like to build something similar like this:

[image: a busy cat]

I know how to bind one slider into one textbox, but then I don't know how to display values\ from different slider in same textbox in time format.

xaml:

```
<Calendar Margin="448,220,369,39" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" Name="calendarMain" SelectedDatesChanged="calendarMain_SelectedDatesChanged"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderMinutes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="Visible" Name="txtboxCal" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="321,223,0,0"/>
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="sliderHours" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" Minimum="0" Maximum="24" Margin="321,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="28"/>
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="sliderMinutes" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" Minimum="0" Maximum="60" Margin="321,287,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

EDIT

I managed to do that using Multibinding like this

```
<TextBlock Margin="836,423,107,25" Name="txtBlockTime">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}:{1}">
                    <Binding ElementName="sliderHours" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="sliderMinutes" Path="Value"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
```

Thank you for tip :)

Comment: And the Bindings should be TwoWay?

Comment: @Clemens Yes it should be TwoWay

Comment: Take a look at MultiBinding with an appropriate IMultiValueConverter, which would convert two double values to a time string and vice versa.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the tip. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use converter in this behavior.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TimeToStringMulti x:Key="TimeToStringMulti" />
</Window.Resources>
<TextBlock Margin="836,423,107,25" Name="txtBlockTime">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TimeToStringMulti}" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="sliderHours" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="sliderMinutes" Path="Value"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
```

And Converter.cs

```cs
    public class TimeToStringMulti: IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}:{1}", values[0], values[1] );
        }
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string[] param = (value as string).Split(':');
            return new Object[]{double.Parse(param[0]), double.Parse(param[1])};
        }
    }
```